# Confirmation for custom action in Material Tabel [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, action, confirmation, material-table

Is it possible to add confirmation to custom action for example

```
actions={[
    {
      icon: 'save',
      tooltip: 'Confirm',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => { /* something */}
    }
  ]}
```

I want to something like in `editable.onRowDelete`:

[image]

EDIT:
I want to create my own action in `actions` property. For example action of `Cancel reservation`. After click this action button this row change like above and waiting for acceptation. After confirm it do something (for example post to API).

Comment: Seems like it is possible with [component overriding](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        columns: [
            {title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
            {title: 'Surname', field: 'surname'},
            {title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric'},
            {
                title: 'Birth Place',
                field: 'birthCity',
                lookup: {34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa'},
            },
        ],
        data: [
            {name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63},
            {
                name: 'Zerya Betül',
                surname: 'Baran',
                birthYear: 2017,
                birthCity: 34,
            },
        ],
    });

    return (
        <MaterialTable
            title="Editable Example"
            columns={state.columns}
            data={state.data}
            editable={{
                onRowAdd: (newData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            resolve();
                            setState((prevState) => {
                                const data = [...prevState.data];
                                data.push(newData);
                                return {...prevState, data};
                            });
                        }, 600);
                    }),
                onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            resolve();
                            if (oldData) {
                                setState((prevState) => {
                                    const data = [...prevState.data];
                                    data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                    return {...prevState, data};
                                });
                            }
                        }, 600);
                    }),
                onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            resolve();
                            setState((prevState) => {
                                const data = [...prevState.data];
                                data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                                return {...prevState, data};
                            });
                        }, 600);
                    }),
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

[Source](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/)

**Updated Code**

```
import React, {forwardRef} from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

import {AddBox, ArrowUpward, Check, ChevronLeft, ChevronRight, Clear, DeleteOutline, Edit, FilterList, FirstPage, LastPage, Remove, Save, SaveAlt, Search, ViewColumn} from '@material-ui/icons';

export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        columns: [
            {title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
            {title: 'Surname', field: 'surname'},
            {title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric'},
            {
                title: 'Birth Place',
                field: 'birthCity',
                lookup: {34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa'},
            },
        ],
        data: [
            {name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63},
            {
                name: 'Zerya Betül',
                surname: 'Baran',
                birthYear: 2017,
                birthCity: 34,
            },
        ],
    });

    const tableIcons = {
        Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Save: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Save {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowUpward {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref}/>),
        ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref}/>)
    };

    function clickHandler(event) {
        alert('worked');
    }

    return (
        <MaterialTable
            icons={tableIcons}
            title="Editable Example"
            columns={state.columns}
            data={state.data}
            actions={[
                {
                    icon: tableIcons.Save,
                    tooltip: 'Save User',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
                }
            ]}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I mean that I create my own action in `actions` property. For example action `Cancel reservation`. After click this action button this row change like above and waiting for acceptation. After confirm it do something (for example post to API).

Comment: @sqtr I have added another example. Please check it, hope it helps you.

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I just updated the image to perform to you my expected effect. I am thinking about effect after clicking `delete` button but for custom action (using action property). For example let's see on your example above. After clicking `Save user` button this row changes into confirmation `Are you sure you want to save this user ?` After clicking `cancel` it reterns to previous view. After clicking `save/submit` it executes some method.

Comment: I understand but that will tough I think. why not you use confirmation dialogue and gets user's decision like yes or no and then you can call other method based on the decision.